# Page is loading twice when using angular ui-router and "resolve"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, resolve

I'm using Angular 1.5.5, Angular-ui-router 0.2.18, angular-meteor-promiser 1.1.0 and meteor 1.3.3

In my application I use the following route definition:
(There are many other states) :

```js
function routerConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $stateProvider
      .state('auditionExtExec', {
        url: '/AuditionExtExecute/:id',
        templateUrl: 'client/auditions/auditionExtExec.html',
        resolve: {
          auditionsubs: function($promiser) {
            "use strict";
            console.log('in resolve');
            return $promiser.subscribe('auditions');
          },
        },
        controller: 'AuditionExtExecCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
      })
```

The controller is :

```js
angular
  .module('brgo')
  .controller('AuditionExtExecCtrl', function($state, $stateParams, $scope, $reactive, $promiser, auditionsubs) {

    var vm = this;
    $reactive(vm).attach($scope);
    vm.auditionId = $stateParams.id;

    vm.subscribe('auditions');

    vm.start = false;
    vm.auditionResults = {};
    var currentDate = new Date();

    vm.autorun(() => {
      vm.audition = Auditions.findOne({
        _id: vm.auditionId
      });
    });

    vm.addNewExecution = function() {

      vm.auditionResults.auditions = angular.copy(vm.audition.auditions);
      AuditionExecs.insert(vm.auditionResults);


    };

    vm.startaudition = function() {

      vm.start = true;

    };

  });
```

The purpose of this page is to display the contact of the record from `audition` MongoDb table and write results to `AuditionExec` MongoDb table

When the application run, everything looks OK.
However, when I'm in the `auditionExtExec` state and I copy the URL to a new window, the view in the new window is presented twice.
When I remove the `$promiser` from the resolve, it looks like it works fine

Comment: Hard to help without seeing more. Can you try to replicate a minimal example in Plunker?

Comment: While building the Plunker example I removed the $promiser.subscribe and it works, so I'm xclosing my question

Answer (score 0):

Remove promiser.subscribe and the problem disappear